# Is it possible to do partial gamma adjust using OpenCV's LUT?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

According to [OpenCV Gamma Correction](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/), we could adjust the whole image's gamma by OpenCV's `LUT()`:

```
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

    return cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

I was wondering if is possible to do partial gamma correction?

For example, here's an under exposed doll:

[image: Underexposure doll]

I just want to adjust the gamma of the doll, and keep other part still the same.

[image: Ad hoc demo]

I've read the [official doc of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut), it seems that there's no parameter to specific image's partial position.

Comment: You could pass a Numpy slice of your image to your function `image[top:bottom, left:right] = adjust_gamma(image[top:bottom, left:right], gamma)` but you'll get an ugly discontinuity around the edges.

Comment: in C++ you can use subimages and som functions allow to use masks. Not sure about numpy.

Comment: You guys need to chat :-) https://stackoverflow.com/q/60543113/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a Numpy slice of your image to your function, but you'll get an ugly discontinuity around the edges.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
    invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
    table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
        for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

    return cv2.LUT(image, table)

image = cv2.imread('doll.jpg')
image[200:1600, 800:2100] = adjust_gamma(image[200:1600, 800:2100], 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's ugly and discontinuity, I'll figure out how to make it more smooth.

Comment: @pvd let me know how you smooth it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543113/how-to-apply-brightness-to-only-a-part-of-image?noredirect=1#60543113